# can't access web site with same name as AD domain name

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, domain-name

their internal Windows/AD domain name is blahblahblah.com and their public website is blahblahblah.com and they can't see their website while on the office network (the web site loads just fine from anywhere else). How do I fix this so they can see their public web site internally?

Comment: Also, check out the assorted information on best practices for Active Directory naming. [Here's a thread I made about the same problem](http://serverfault.com/q/567775/118258), [here's a link to one of Mark's blog posts where he talks about it](http://www.mdmarra.com/2013/07/more-documentation-from-microsoft-about.html), and [here's a link to a Technet article that talks about best practices for AD naming](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738121%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You rename the internal Active Directory domain to be someInternalName.blahblahblah.com.

Answer (score 2):

Create a **www** host in blahblahblah.com zone internaly and make it point to your public IP.

If you really want to use the blahblahblah.com without the www, you can check, the name should resolve to your DC, so add the IIS role on the DC, add the domain blahblahblah.com in IIS, and do a 302 redirect to www.blahblahblah.com.

Comment: Please do NOT install IIS on your DC... Complete violation of security best practice.